# IP Address printing (swift)

Tags: api, ip

I am trying to get my ip address by using the ipify api.  I have found a few github projects to look at it, but i'm still confused.  The best github project i found is https://github.com/AlbanPerli/APPublicIP  But it prints out not just the ip address but some extra words. it prints out "optional (222.93.883.33)"...  I just want the numbers not the word "optional or the "()".  I have looked through the code but havent seen anything about the word "optional" or "()". Its only 2 files of code. Very simple and clear, just can't figure out how to just show the ip, no words.  I thought maybe its because its "https://api.ipify.org?format=json" and not another api, that is one of the api links.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

it's printing optional (..) like you've described because the data type returned to you is not a **string** - it's an **optional string**. If you do:

```
if let ip = resultReturnedByLibrary {
  print(ip)
}
```

then it wont print the extra information.

This is known as unwrapping the optional.